# gwt 2.8 throws exception when compiling with guava 20

Tags: gwt, guava

I am trying to upgrade to the newly released guava-gwt 20. I am getting this exception when I do a gwt compile.  I did not get any errors prior to upgrading to guava 20. I am using the gwt 2.8.0.  Is there a module I need to reference? Much appreciated!

```
[INFO]    Tracing compile failure path for type 'java.util.concurrent.Future'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/Eric/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava-gwt/20.0/guava-gwt-20.0.jar!/java/util/super/java/util/concurrent/Future.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 32: No source code is available for type java.lang.InterruptedException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]    Tracing compile failure path for type 'java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/Eric/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava-gwt/20.0/guava-gwt-20.0.jar!/java/util/super/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 30: No source code is available for type java.lang.InterruptedException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]    [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems likely that this is a Guava bug. Can you add `<inherits name="java.lang.Lang"/>` to your `.gwt.xml` file and let me know if that helps?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, adding `<inherits name="java.lang.Lang"/>` does not always help. I have just created a guava bug [#2622](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2622), let's see what the outcome is.

Comment: #2622 sounds like a different problem (which I will also take a look at -- thanks). It would be good to hear from the original poster whether the `<inherits>` line helps there.

Comment: I have also seen this issue, I still don't know why (I think something is wrong with the cache). Cleaning the `gwt-unitCache` folder before every build helped me to fix it. Now with the missing jars (see guava #2622) + a clean before the build everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be [a Guava bug](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2638). Until we fix it, you can work around it by adding `<inherits name="java.lang.Lang"/>` to your `.gwt.xml`.